# Spring boot: @ConfigurationProperties not satisfied on test

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I'm getting this exception on my test excution:

> UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'net.gencat.transversal.espaidoc.mongo.GridFSTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'resourceProperties'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'net.gencat.transversal.espaidoc.ResourcesConfigProperties' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.

So, I think message is so clear enough: `ResourcesConfigProperties is not satisfied`.

My test:

```
RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest()
public class GridFSTest {

    @Autowired
    private GridFsTemplate gridFsTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private ResourcesConfigProperties resourceProperties;

    public URL getHugeResource() {
        try {
            return Paths
                .get(this.resourceProperties.getHuge())
                .toUri()
                .toURL();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void storeHugeFile() throws IOException {
        URL resource = this.getHugeResource();

        this.gridFsTemplate.store(
            resource.openStream(),
            resource.getPath(),
            "mime"
        );
    }
}
```

and `ResourcesConfigProperties` is:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "files")
public class ResourcesConfigProperties {

    private String huge;

    /**
     * @return the huge
     */
    public String getHuge() {
        return huge;
    }

    /**
     * @param huge the huge to set
     */
    public void setHuge(String huge) {
        this.huge = huge;
    }

}
```

into my `src/test/resources` I have my `application.properties` file:

```
files.huge: /home/jcabre/Downloads/1GB.zip
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Main Spring boot application:

```
@SpringBootApplication(
    //scanBasePackages = { "cat.gencat.ctti.canigo.arch.web.rs" },
    exclude = JmxAutoConfiguration.class
)
@EnableConfigurationProperties({
    ApiProperties.class,
    FileStoreProperties.class
})
@Import(RedisConfiguration.class)
public class ApiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApiApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: what does your Main Spring boot application look like?

Comment: I've just edited post.

Comment: Add `@Component` to `ResourcesConfigProperties` because `@ConfigurationProperties` does not import any of the spring annotations that create a bean.

Comment: You need to add `@Configuration` to `ResourcesConfigProperties` class otherwise it will not create a bean of this class in the spring container and `@Autowired` will not work.

Answer (score 14):

### TL;DR:

It is happening, because the `@ConfigurationProperties` are not managed by the application context **you build in tests**, although they will be load when the application launches, because you have `@EnableConfigurationProperties` on your app main class.

`@EnableConfigurationProperties` on main class only affect the application context you have when you `bootRun`, **but not that in a  `@SpringBootTest`**. The application context you build in tests could be, under many circumstances, distinct with that of `bootRun`, just like in your case.

You can add `@Component` to make the context be aware of it, both in `gradle bootRun` and in `gradle test`. It's the easiest way, but not 100% the suggested way.

---

#### More proper way with details if you have time

Instead, you can add `@EnableConfigurationProperties({Config1.class, Config2.class})` in a `@SpringBootTest`, to inject only some of the configuration properties class into the context, to avoid injection overhead.

It would be like:

```
//@RunWith(SpringRunner.class) // for JUnit4 in Spring
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class) // for JUnit5 in Spring. 
@SpringBootTest
@EnableConfigurationProperties({
        ResourcesConfigProperties.class,
})
@Data
public class ConfigsTest {

    @Autowired
    private ResourcesConfigProperties resourceConfigProperties;

    ...

}
```

---

Better yet, you can use `@SpringBootTest(classes={})`: classes within `{}` are those you want the application context of `@SpringBootTest` to manage(creation, initialization, loading properties from yaml files, and so on). Then you don't have to load all the context, but only part of it.

You can group all classes of `@ConfigurationProperties` in one class of `@Configuration`, and put it in the `classes={}` of `@SpringBootTest`, instead of repeating this list of `@ConfigurationProperties` everywhere. Something like:

```
//@RunWith(SpringRunner.class) // for JUnit4 in Spring
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class) // for JUnit5 in Spring. 
@SpringBootTest(classes = {
    TestConfiguration.class
})
@Data
public class ConfigsTest {

    @Autowired
    private ResourcesConfigProperties resourceConfigProperties;


    ...

}
```

`TestConfiguration.java`:

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties({
        ResourcesConfigProperties.class,
})
@Configuration
public class TestConfiguration {
}
```

Comment: Last but not least, add a `@NoArgsConstructor` as well as `@AllArgsConstructor` to the mapping class; that bite me again. And, the fields cannot be declared `final`, nor can you use `@Builder` on that class. It should not be declared as `@Component`, neither. `@Data` is needed, of course.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `ResourcesConfigProperties` to your `EnableConfigurationProperties` annotation in the main spring boot class, this will load and create a bean out of the `ResourceConfigProperties` for you

You could also add `@Component` to your `ResourceConfigProperties` if you do not want to add it to the `EnableConfigurationProperties` annotation.

When using the `SpringBootTest` or any slice test it will use whatever is annotated on, or beans defined within the main `SpringBootApplication` within the test context.

Answer (score -2):

You also need to annotate `ResourcesConfigProperties` class with `@Configuration` as below, otherwise it will not create a bean of this class in the spring container.

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "files")
public class ResourcesConfigProperties {

    private String huge;

    /**
     * @return the huge
     */
    public String getHuge() {
        return huge;
    }

    /**
     * @param huge the huge to set
     */
    public void setHuge(String huge) {
        this.huge = huge;
    }

}
```