Spring TestPropertySource params test use
I am implemented a bean class to store some parameters I would like to use in my software:
/**
 * Parameters related to the H2 Database:
 * <ul>
 * <li>{@code uri}: The H2 address to the H2 Database</li>
 * <li>{@code userName}: The H2 username</li>
 * <li>{@code password}: The H2 password</li>
 * </ul>
 */
@Data
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "h2")
@Primary
public class H2Params {

    /**
     * URI Address to local H2 Database: {@code h2.uri}
     */
    private String uri = H2_URI_DEFAULT;

    /**
     * Username of local H2 Database: {@code h2.userName}
     */
    private String userName = H2_USERNAME_DEFAULT;

    /**
     * Password of local H2 Database: {@code h2.password}
     */
    private String password = H2_PASSWORD_DEFAULT;

}

It works quite well with parameters files application.yml like:
---
app:
  name: testApp

h2:
  uri: "jdbc:h2:/var/lib/chronos/chronos;CACHE_SIZE=131072;TRACE_LEVEL_SYSTEM_OUT=1"
  userName: "testUser"
  password: "testPassword"

My problem is that I can't understand how to use this approach in unit test.
I wrote a test like this one:
@SpringBootTest(classes = {H2Params.class})
@TestPropertySource(properties = {"h2.uri = jdbc:h2:~/tmp/test",
                                  "h2.userName = testUser",
                                  "h2.password = testPassword"})
class ParamsTest {

    @Autowired
    H2Params h2Params;

    @Test
    void test06() {
        assertEquals("jdbc:h2:~/tmp/test", h2Params.getUri());
    }

    @Test
    void test07() {
        assertEquals("testUser", h2Params.getUserName());
    }

    @Test
    void test08() {
        assertEquals("testPassword", h2Params.getPassword());
    }
 

All the tests fail because the specified parameters are not used.
Is my approach wrong?
As far as I understood the Spring documentation the tests should pass
I expect the test to pass

Did you try adding @EnableConfigurationProperties on your test class?

it works !!! But why this annotation is needed ?

see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52605568/spring-boot-configurationproperties-not-satisfied-on-test and
